# Need azure login user Details in our MVC web application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My web application is Configured with Azure App Service and use Azure AD login, We need azure login user Details in our web application, Please suggest us how can we get login user details?

Comment: The Azure AD credentials are only accessible if you have Azure portal access where your App Service is hosted. Either contact for portal credentials or simply ask the admin to provide the Azure AD credentials for this App Service.

Comment: We are looking for currently logged in user of Azure AD from our web application? I wish it make sense. please suggest us for process to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, both of them described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims

1. Take the user details from the HTTP headers which Azure App Service will inject (e.g. for Azure AD, the `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN` would include the full [ID token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) issue by Azure AD)
2. Make a REST request to `/.auth/me`.